# Значение исключения

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, mysqlconnector

При работе с `mysql` получаю такую ошибку :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anon/Desktop/AP/AP_2_0.py", line 165, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sqlzapros)
  File "C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 561, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 525, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 427, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'vallues:values2' for key 'line'
```

Я понимаю что можно сделать обработку исключения,этого : `mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError`

Но мне хотелось бы получить непосредственно значение данной строки,что бы в дальнейшем убрать ее из строки запроса.

Comment: Нужно получить значение на котором выбило это исключение.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить только саму ошибку (без остального стека) в виде строки:

```
In [32]: import traceback

In [33]: d = {}

In [34]: try:
    ...:     print(d['NOT_EXISTING_KEY'])
    ...: except Exception as e:
    ...:     exinfo = traceback.format_exception_only(type(e), e)
    ...:     raise
    ...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-6d43cc6d6822> in <module>()
      1 try:
----> 2     print(d['NOT_EXISTING_KEY'])
      3 except Exception as e:
      4     exinfo = traceback.format_exception_only(type(e), e)
      5     raise

KeyError: 'NOT_EXISTING_KEY'
In [36]: exinfo
Out[36]: ["KeyError: 'NOT_EXISTING_KEY'\n"]

In [37]: ''.join(exinfo)
Out[37]: "KeyError: 'NOT_EXISTING_KEY'\n"
```

Если просто перехватить строковое представление исключения, то часто теряется ценная информация.

Пример:

```
In [38]: try:
    ...:     print(d['AAA'])
    ...: except Exception as e:
    ...:     err = str(e)
    ...:

In [39]: err
Out[39]: "'AAA'"
```

получилось совершенно непонятное сообщение об ошибке.

PS в случае перехвата **любого** (`Exception`) исключения лучше в конце всегда добавлять `raise`, т.е. завершать выполнение с ошибкой, чтобы избежать неприятных сюрпризов

PPS Еще стоило бы вести "логи" того, что происходит в процессе выполнения - для этого можно воспользоваться модулем [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html):

```
import logging
from pymysql.err import MySQLError

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    cursor.execute(sqlzapros)
except MySQLError as e:
    log.exception("message")
    raise
```

Comment: 1- стоит упомянуть почему не просто str(e) здесь 2- вычленять значения из текстового представления исключения это хак. Лучше в том месте где задаётся ключ, его  в качестве аргумента привесить к исключению явно (если наверх стека нужно с исключением информацию передать). К примеру как это сделано с e.returncode атрибутом у subprocess.CalledProcessError.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    assert False, "err_text '1' > '2' !"
except AssertionError as ex:
    print(type(ex))  # <class 'AssertionError'>
    print(str(ex))  # "err_text '1' > '2' !"  

import sys
try:
    raise UserWarning("err_text '1' > '2' !")
except Exception:
    exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    print(exc_type.__name__)  # "UserWarning"
    print(exc_val)  # "err_text '1' > '2' !"


import traceback
def full_tb_write(*args):
    '''логировать traceback'''
    if not args:
        exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    elif len(args) == 3:
        exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb = args
    elif len(args) == 1:
        exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb = args[0].__class__, args[0], args[0].__traceback__

    traceback.print_tb(exc_tb, file=sys.stdout)
    with open('_log.log', 'a') as log:
        traceback.print_tb(exc_tb, file=log)

try:
    raise UserWarning("err_text '1' > '2' !")
except Exception:
    full_tb_write(*sys.exc_info())
try:
    raise UserWarning("err_text '1' > '2' !")
except Exception as ex:
    full_tb_write(ex)
try:
    raise UserWarning("err_text '1' > '2' !")
except:
    full_tb_write()


import contextlib
with contextlib.suppress(KeyError, AssertionError):
    {None: None}['key']

try:
    {None: None}['key']
except (KeyError, AssertionError):
    pass
except Exception:
    raise
else:
    pass
finally:
    pass
```

`получить непосредственно значение данной строки`

```
import re

err_list = []
for i in iterable:
    try:
        do(i)  # "1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'vallues:values2' for key 'line'"
    except mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError as ex:
        e = str(ex)
        if "Duplicate entry" in e:
            vals = re.findall(r'\'(.+?)\'', e)
            (val1, val2), key = vals[0].split(':', 1), vals[1]
            err_list.append([key, val1, val2])  # ['line', 'vallues', 'values2']
```